# Is it possible to make \includepdf follow odd / even page margins?

Tags: pdfpages

For my PhD thesis, I'm trying to include various multipage .pdf files as appendices using `\includepdf`. However, it is centering the pdf, rather than following the odd / even page margins. Is there a way to fix this to follow the alternate margins?

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\urlstyle{rm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Then within the appendix chapter:

```
\includepdf[pages={-},scale=.8,pagecommand={}]{ptsurvey.pdf}
```

Comment: you can try `\includepdf[pages={-},scale=.8,pagecommand={},offset=1cm 0cm]{ptsurvey.pdf}`

Comment: Tweaking the offset dimensions, that works. Thanks.

Comment: You are missing the package `everythingbutthekitchensink`. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".